# JSONObject and for loop not working in RecycleView

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I am trying to pull a list of Geofence names from the database using JSON and for loop, but it does not add anything on the RecycleView.

However if i manually add a string such as the example comment `mTextNames.add("HARRY POTTER")`and it shows up just fine.

```
private void initGeofenceNames(){

    final JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, HttpUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.d(TAG, "GeofenceManageListActivity: jsonObject called");

                    mGeofenceNames.add(jsonObject.getString("geof_name"));

                    for (String s : mGeofenceNames){
                        mTextNames.add(s.toString());
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "GeofenceManageListActivity: " + error.toString());
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    //mTextNames.add("HARRY POTTER");

    initRecyclerView();
}
```

EDIT:

```
private void initRecyclerView(){
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.geofenceManagementListRecyclerView);
    GeofenceManagementListRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new GeofenceManagementListRecyclerViewAdapter(mTextNames, this );
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}
```

Comment: Please share your JSON response.

Comment: Can you post your code inside method `initRecyclerView`. And 1 thing, when you get data successfully, you don't have any function to update data in `RecyclerView`

Comment: You can add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after your loop for to notify data changed for your adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use as your method

```
 private void initGeofenceNames(){

        final JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, HttpUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.d(TAG, "GeofenceManageListActivity: jsonObject called");

                        mGeofenceNames.add(jsonObject.getString("geof_name"));

                        for (String s : mGeofenceNames){
                            mTextNames.add(s.toString());
                        }
    initRecyclerView();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "GeofenceManageListActivity: " + error.toString());
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

        //mTextNames.add("HARRY POTTER");


    }
```

Second Option
create class level adapter veriable
as

```
private GeofenceManagementListRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
private void initRecyclerView(){
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.geofenceManagementListRecyclerView);
    adapter = new GeofenceManagementListRecyclerViewAdapter(mTextNames, this );
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

private void initGeofenceNames(){

    final JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, HttpUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.d(TAG, "GeofenceManageListActivity: jsonObject called");

                    mGeofenceNames.add(jsonObject.getString("geof_name"));

                    for (String s : mGeofenceNames){
                        mTextNames.add(s.toString());
                    }
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "GeofenceManageListActivity: " + error.toString());
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    //mTextNames.add("HARRY POTTER");

    initRecyclerView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put "initRecyclerView()" inside onResponse

```
              try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d(TAG, "GeofenceManageListActivity: jsonObject called");

              mGeofenceNames.add(jsonObject.getString("geof_name"));

                for (String s : mGeofenceNames){
                    mTextNames.add(s.toString());
                }

                 initRecyclerView();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
```

Answer (score 0):

add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` like below

```
 @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

        for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d(TAG, "GeofenceManageListActivity: jsonObject called");

                mGeofenceNames.add(jsonObject.getString("geof_name"));

                for (String s : mGeofenceNames){
                    mTextNames.add(s.toString());
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //change here

    }
},
```